# How do I make a horizontal data list print into a series of columns?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a data list that looks like this: Date=27-06-2023; Time=12:16:15.8650000; TraceP...
How do I make that into separate columns with Date, Time, etc. as the titles?
Ex. Date          Time
27-06-2023    12:16:15.8650000
I am using pandas.

So far I am just printing it like this:

N=[]

for f in csv_files:

```
# read the csv file
rf = pd.read_csv(f)
N.append(rf) #save in the massive file

# drop last few rows
rf.drop(rf.tail(16385).index,
    inplace = True)

# print the location and filename
# print('Location:', f)
print('File Name:', f.split("\\")[-1])
  
# print the content
print('Content:')
display(rf)
print()
```

In column_subset=['Date', 'Time', 'TracePoints', 'TSamp', 'TimeUnits', 'AmpToVolts', 'TraceMaxVolts', 'PTime', 'STime']
usecols=column_subset
N

Out[                                           ATF v1.00
0  Date=27-06-2023; Time=14:46:24.1960000; TraceP...,
ATF v1.00
0  Date=27-06-2023; Time=14:46:24.1960000; TraceP...,
ATF v1.00
0  Date=27-06-2023; Time=14:46:24.1960000; TraceP...,
ATF v1.00
0  Date=27-06-2023; Time=14:46:24.1960000; TraceP...,

Answer (score 1):

From your question, it looks like your data in the CSV file is not properly formatted. Hence pd.read_csv() will most likely not work out of the box. Normally in a CSV file, the columns should be separated by commas, but in your case, they are separated by semicolons and the column names are included with the data itself.

A possible solution to this is to read your data as a simple text file first, parse each line to split the values at the semicolons, then extract the column names and data from each split part. Here's an example which may work.

```
import pandas as pd

N = []

for f in csv_files:
    # read the file as a text file
    with open(f, 'r') as file:
        data = []
        for line in file:
            # split the line at semicolons
            parts = line.split(";")
            row = {}
            for part in parts:
                # split the part at the equals sign
                name_value = part.split("=")
                if len(name_value) == 2:
                    # the part is a column name and value
                    name = name_value[0].strip()
                    value = name_value[1].strip()
                    row[name] = value
            data.append(row)
    # convert the data to a DataFrame
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    N.append(df)
```

Comment: That works but it does not read all the files, it only displays data for 1. Do you know why that might be?